# hide and show lineEdit with QComboBox in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I need to create application which will work with database and I need to connect QCombobox with lineEdits(1,2,3). I have QComboBox with two items(1,2) and I want to hide lineEdits(2,3) when I change to item 2. And when I change back to item 1 I want to show lineEdits(2,3) and hide lineEdit 1. Can somebody help me? :-) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You simply connect the currentIndexChanged(int index) signal of your QComboxBox to a slot in your class and hide/show the QLineEdit's depending on the the value of index.

```
  QObject::connect(myComboxBox, SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(int)), 
        this, SLOT(onComboxBoxCurrentIndexChanged(int)));
```

The slot can be implemented as follows:

```
MyClass::onComboxBoxCurrentIndexChanged(int index)
{
  if(index == 0){
    lineEdit1->setVisible(false);
    lineEdit2->setVisible(true);
    lineEdit3->setVisible(true);
  }
  else{
    lineEdit1->setVisible(true);
    lineEdit2->setVisible(false);
    lineEdit3->setVisible(false);
  }
}
```

Note that your class must be a subclass of QObject for the slot to work. If you don't know how signal and slots work I would recommend reading a tutorial first.

See http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html